# How to get rid of multiple sub files created while usng VIM in Windows

Tags: windows, vim, text-editor

Vim is creating multiple sub files when editing a file under Windows. Please let me know how can I get rid off from the files like - `.app.js.un~` or `app.js~`.

FYI - I also closed the command prompt and still these temporary files exists in the folder.

I saved the files with `:wq!`

Let me know what settings/config I need to change or what I am doing wrong with the command.

Please check the screenshot -

[image: Capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<file>.un~` is an undo history file and let you undo/redo changes (<kbd>u</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>) even after closing and opening again the file later.

`<file>~` is a backup file with all file contents before your last change.

If you really want to disable them do:

```
:set noundofile
:set nobackup
```

Or add the same commands into `<Programs>/Vim/_vimrc`.
Note that the undo file is not enabled by default, so you can just delete or comment the `set undofile` command you will find in your `<Programs>/Vim/_vimrc` file.